# Facebook Graph API search places by category

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm currently developing an Android app that uses Facebook graph API to get pages/places based on user's location. I also want to filter the results by category, like restaurants for example.
For now I'm just searching for the name "restaurant" like this:
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=restaurant&type=place&center=37.76,-122.427&distance=1000

The problem is that it wont find pages/places that don't have name "restaurant" and it also returns places that don´t have anything to do with restaurants. I also have the language issue, in non-English countries my search will fail completely.

A possible solution I am considering is to get all the places in a range and parse them in my app for the category or name. Obviously this brings a lot of overhead to my app.

I was wondering if there is a better solution like using FQL to get filtered results?

Answer (score 2):

There should be, but I can't unravel how.

This FQL query will get you information about all places near a known location:

```
SELECT name, page_id, categories, description, general_info 
   FROM page WHERE page_id IN 
     (SELECT page_id FROM place WHERE 
        distance(latitude, longitude, "37.76", "-122.427") < 1000
      )
```

The `categories` field is an array with the values `id` and `name`. Looking at these results, there are a series of category names like "Restaurant": "Italian Restaurant", "Bar/Restaurant, etc.

What I can't find is a way to add a `WHERE categories` clause to this that returns data.

Comment: Thank-you, I can try that out but I think that this gives me the same results using the basic graph API request. I believe the reason why you can´t use the "WHERE categories" is because its not a Index-able column as you can see [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page).

Comment: Not true. Your first `WHERE` clause in FQL has to be indexable. After that, you can add `WHERE` criteria on non-indexable columns to limit your results. The biggest difference with the FQL vs the Graph API query is the addition of the categories field which allows you to definitively identify that "Hog & Rocks" is a restaurant.

Comment: Good point. But using the Graph API I can also get the list of pages and check each page´s category field. So isn´t possible to add a - AND WHERE category = 'restaurant' to you second clause like in regular SQL?

Comment: What gets returned by the two calls are different. Look at ID 21653874551894. Graph API shows it is a "Local Business" while FQL shows it is an "Ice Cream Parlor" and a "Restaurant".

Comment: In FQL the category is an array. I've tried every variant of `category`, `category.name`, `category.id`, `=`, `IN` and `strpos()` I could think of in my `WHERE` queries and can't get any of these to return data. I've dug through the docs and SO and I don't see any guidance there.

Comment: Interesting... up until now I have only used the graph API. I'll cary on searching for a solution and hopefully Facebook will add this filter in a near future.