# How can I get all restaurants nearby me using Facebook API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm having some trouble using Facebook API to retrieve all the restaurants nearby a specific location.

I have found these solutions: 
[Facebook places: order results by distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166500/facebook-places-order-results-by-distance) and [Facebook Graph API search places by category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11147947/facebook-graph-api-search-places-by-category) but I didn't find a way to filter the restaurant and get the same results of [this query](https://www.facebook.com/search/me/places-near/273819889375819/places/intersect).

Does anyone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try out  this fql . was hunting for an answer for this question for long untill i found this [stack overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15722538/fql-query-through-category-list)

```
SELECT page_id, type, categories
FROM page
WHERE page_id IN
  (SELECT
     page_id,
     latitude,
     longitude
   FROM place
   WHERE distance(latitude, longitude, '-30.03852', '-51.17877') < 50000
   LIMIT 100)
AND type="RESTAURANT/CAFE"
```

you can modify the latitude and longitude values in sub query and filter the results by type. but please note that fql is deprecated by api v2.0

**sample output**

```
"data": [
{
  "page_id": 202457279801080, 
  "type": "RESTAURANT/CAFE", 
  "categories": [
    {
      "id": 185459711490789, 
      "name": "Brazilian Restaurant"
    }, 
    {
      "id": 168976549819329, 
      "name": "French Restaurant"
    }, 
    {
      "id": 163300367054197, 
      "name": "Seafood Restaurant"
    }
  ]
},
```

refer the above mentioned thread for more details .

Comment: After one year I changed two jobs, I barely remember why I was asking for this question but since there are no other answers I am gonna accept your answer. Thank you ;)

Comment: @Yuri when i searched for this question on google. this was the first result, added the answer in case some one stumble upon this page cause of same problem :) . thanks

Comment: Unfortunately FQL is no longer available - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/